# Which levels have collectibles in "Where's my water?"?

Tags: wheres-my-water

I was playing "Where's  my water?" and I wanted to get all the collectibles. In which levels are they located?

Comment: Finally got them all =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Collection items***

- **Meet Swampy**

  - Level 1-7   - "Shiny Scale Shampoo"
  - Level 1-10 - "Suds-A-Lot Soap"
  - Level 1-12 - "Lucky Loofah"
  - Level 1-14 - "Toothbrush"
  - Level 1-16 - "Minty Icing"
  - Level 1-19 - "Finicky Floss"
- **Troubled Waters**

  - Level 2-4   - “Lazy Flipper”
  - Level 2-8   - “Nessie”
  - Level 2-10 - “Reading Goggle”
  - Level 2-14 - “Party Hat”
  - Level 2-15 - “Life Preserver”
  - Level 2-20 - “Scope”
- **Under Pressure**

  - Level 3-3  - “Picnic Basket”
  - Level 3-5  - “Talk Box”
  - Level 3-8  - “Sugary Soap”
  - Level 3-12 - “Spoon-apault”
  - Level 3-15 - “Chip”
  - Level 3-18 - “Momma Teapot”
- **Sink or Swim**

  - Level 4-1   - “Bow”
  - Level 4-4   - “Back Scratcher”
  - Level 4-9   - “Poetry Perfume”
  - Level 4-15 - “Heart Shaped Box”
  - Level 4-17 - “Rose”
  - Level 4-20 - “Teddy Bear”
- **Change is Good**

  - Level 5-2   - “Big Apple”
  - Level 5-5   - “Artistic Woman”
  - Level 5-8   - “Tiny Taxi”
  - Level 5-12 - “Gyration Junkie”
  - Level 5-14 - “Multipurpose Hat”
  - Level 5-17 - “Scooter Penrose”
- **Boiling Point**

  - Level 6-2   - “The Glider”
  - Level 6-4   - “Claw Cleaners”
  - Level 6-8   - “Hypothesis Hat”
  - Level 6-12 - “Water Cloth”
  - Level 6-15 - “Golden Locks”
  - Level 6-19 - “All Terrain Marker”
- **Stretched Thin**

  - Level 7-4  - “Time Traveling Hat”
  - Level 7-6  - “Cone of Authority”
  - Level 7-10 - “Plot Device”
  - Level 7-14 - “One Man Band”
  - Level 7-16 - “Good Morning Machine”
  - Level 7-20 - “Heartbreak Accelerator”
- **Caution to the Wind**

  - Level 8-3 - "Polka Dot Stamp"
  - Level 8-5 - "Soup Bowl"
  - Level 8-8 - "Hand Flipper"
  - Level 8-11 - "Rotisserie Rotators"
  - Level 8-14 - "Figurine Head"
  - Level 8-17 - "Pandora's Box"
- **Rising Tide**

  - Level 9-2 - "Lazy Music Box"
  - Level 9-4 - "Magnet Carrying Case"
  - Level 9-9 - "Bread Launcher"
  - Level 9-11 - "Domino the Fragile Dog"
  - Level 9-16 - "Party Horn"
  - Level 9-20 - "Day of Cake Hat"
- **Out to Dry**

  - Level 10-3 - "Squishy Fishy"
  - Level 10-6 - "Snout Guard"
  - Level 10-8 - "Tail Floatation Device"
  - Level 10-12 - "Double-scope"
  - Level 10-14 - "Twisted Time Teller"
  - Level 10-17 - "Portable Campfire"

Answer (score 3):

Chapter 1: Meet Swampy - 7, 10, 12, 14, 16, 19
Chapter 2: Troubled Waters - 4, 8, 10, 14, 15, 20
Chapter 3: Under Pressure - 3, 5, 8, 12, 15, 18
Chapter 4: Sink or Swim - 1, 4, 9, 15, 17, 20
Chapter 5: Change is Good - 2, 5, 8, 12, 14, 17
Chapter 6: Boiling Point - 2, 4, 8, 12, 15, 19
Chapter 7: Stretched Thin - 4, 6, 10, 14, 16, 20
Chapter 8: Caution to the Wind - 3, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17
Chapter 9: Rising Tide - 2, 4, 9, 11, 16, 20
Chapter 10: Out to Dry - 3, 6, 8, 12, 14, 17

While playing a level, the fact that it has a collectible in it is indicated by a question mark next to the ducks in the top left corner. You can also see which levels you've collected the collectible for on the level select screen.

Comment: I don't find the flashlight in streched thin

Comment: It's in level 7-6, middle section, bottom-right corner

Answer (score 0):

- Level 8-3
- Level 8-5
- Level 8-11
- Level 8-14
- Level 8-17

I think one is missing but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Please add what the item is called aswell =)

Comment: The missing collectible which isn't in your list for chapter 8 is in level 8.